# Self-sizing cells based on AutoLayout for custom UICollelctionViewLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm writing a custom UICollectionViewLayout (there are many reasons why FlowLayout doesn't work for me, they don't matter for this question).

One thing I can't understand is how to use self-sizing cells with custom layout. For example, I have a cell with a textview, that should resize its height. How do I get its height without manual calculations? Is it possible to setup autolayout and somehow get the size of the cell afterwards?

Comment: Yes it can be done with autolayout, but using a label would be better in place of textview. Do you want to change the height of the cell depending upon the height of the textview while editing.

Comment: I need the cell to adjust its height while the user enters text into the textview.

Comment: Then you have to do manual calculations. It wont be possible by using only autolayout.

Comment: It actually works with FlowLayout, but there are other problems with it.